# generate commerce coupon bulkly

Tags: commerce

Is there any way to generate Drupal commerce coupon code bulky?
I found [commerce_coupon_batch](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_coupon_batch) module but it require `Commerce_coupon_ui` module that there is not exist in sub module of  `commerce_coupon version 7.x-2.0-beta1`.

I don't try anything yet, How can I generate coupon code bulky?
I look at db and found there is a table for coupon ,`commerce_coupon` is just sufficient to add record to this table programmatically?

I try below code to create one coupon , but nothing added to coupon list in `admin/commerce/coupons :`

```
$No=$form_state["values"]["code_NO"];
    $type_id=$form_state["values"]["type"];
    $record['type']='discount_coupon';
    $record['code']=commerce_coupon_generate_coupon_code($type_id);
    $record['commerce_discount_reference']['und']['0']['target_id'] =$type_id;
    $record['commerce_coupon_conditions']['und'][0]=Array('condition_name'=>'commerce_coupon_usage_evaluate_usage',
            'condition_settings' =>Array( 'max_usage'=> 1),
            'remove_condition'=> 'Remove',);
ym(entity_get_controller('commerce_coupon')->create($record));
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is good but you forget save `entity` .I hope this get clue to you to achieve your job.

```
$No=$form_state["values"]["code_NO"];
    $type_id=$form_state["values"]["type"];
    $record['type']='discount_coupon';
    $record['code']=commerce_coupon_generate_coupon_code($type_id);
    $record['commerce_discount_reference']['und']['0']['target_id'] =$type_id;
    $record['commerce_coupon_conditions']['und'][0]=Array('condition_name'=>'commerce_coupon_usage_evaluate_usage',
            'condition_settings' =>Array( 'max_usage'=> 1),
            'remove_condition'=> 'Remove',);
$entity=entity_get_controller('commerce_coupon')->create($record);
commerce_coupon_save($entity);
```

Comment: tnx for your attention, yes I found my problem